# Limsup question $ \sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{m=1}^N x_{m-n} \leq N^2 \bigg( \limsup_{n \to \infty} x_n + o(1) \bigg) $

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Reading notes on the [Poincare Recurrence Theorem](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/01/30/254a-lecture-8-the-mean-ergodic-theorem/) and I am a bit stuck with **Theorem 1**.

For a measure preserving dynamical system $T: X \to X$ we have $\mu(T^{-1}E) = \mu(E)$.  Why does it "easily follow" that:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{m=1}^N \mu\bigg(T^n E \cap T^m E\bigg)
\leq N^2 \bigg( \limsup_{n \to \infty} \mu(E \cap T^n E) + o(1) \bigg) $$

---

In fact, let's forget entirely we are dealing with dynamical systems... why is it easily true that for positive numbers $x_k \geq 0$

$$ \sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{m=1}^N x_{m-n}
\leq N^2 \bigg( \limsup_{n \to \infty} x_n + o(1) \bigg) $$

It is not so bad, it's just that everything should be smaller than the limsup:
$\displaystyle \boxed{x_k
\leq  \limsup_{n \to \infty} x_n }$

Why is the $o(1)$ still necessary?